# Why can't python/jupyer notebook find the text file? Where should it be saved?

Tags: python, arrays, text, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to load a text file as an array in python by entering this code:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
    values = loadtxt("values.txt", float)
    mean = sum(values)/len(values)
    print(mean)
```

but when I run the program I get:

```
  OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4b9a39f8b17f> in <module>
      1 from numpy import loadtxt
----> 2 values = loadtxt("values.txt", float)
      3 mean = sum(values)/len(values)
      4 print(mean)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding, max_rows)
    960             fname = os_fspath(fname)
    961         if _is_string_like(fname):
--> 962             fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
    963             fencoding = getattr(fh, 'encoding', 'latin1')
    964             fh = iter(fh)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py in open(path, mode, destpath, encoding, newline)
    264 
    265     ds = DataSource(destpath)
--> 266     return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
    267 
    268 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py in open(self, path, mode, encoding, newline)
    622                                       encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
    623         else:
--> 624             raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
    625 
    626 

OSError: values.txt not found.
```

I have the values.txt file saved in my documents folder. Do I need to save it in some specific folder so Python can find it?

Comment: pass the absolute path instead of just `values.txt`

Comment: Yes, it needs to be *at the path you pass to the function*. `values.txt` will be interpreted as a relative path from your working directory, which apparently is not your documents folder. So just provide the full path.

Comment: I added the path to the function `values=loadtxt("C:\\Users\\Willian\\Documents\\values.txt", float)` but I still get the same error. `@juanpa.arrivillaga`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use **the absolute path**, or use loadtxt("values.txt", float) but then your file **should be in the same folder** with your script/jupyter.